# Angular App-Routing LoadChildren Can't find module

Tags: angular

I am  new to Angular and following a video tutorial. I am stuck on the App-Rounting where it is trying to load child components. Here is the code so far

```
app-routing.module.ts

import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { RouterModule, Routes } from "@angular/router";

import { HomeComponent } from "./home/home.component";

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: "", component: HomeComponent },
  {
    path: "customers",
    loadChildren: "../app/customers/customers.module#CustomersModule"
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)], // add the routes to import array
  exports: [RouterModule], // after import, export the RouterModule after adding appRoutes
  declarations: []
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

I tried change the loadChildren: "../app/customers/customers.module#CustomersModule" to loadChildren: "app/customers/customers.module#CustomersModule"

The file tree structure is the following

```
src\
  app\
    app-routing.module.ts
    customers\
      customers.module.ts
      customers.module.spec.ts
```

I am not sure why it can't find and load the customers.module.ts. At first, I didn't have the customers.moudle.spec.ts and added it but it still throw the same error on the chrome console.

node version is v14.16.0
node version is 6.14.11

Any help is appreciated for this newbie.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your tutorial is old ,you must use [new syntax](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules#lazy-loading-basics)

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'items',
    loadChildren: () => import('./items/items.module').then(m => m.ItemsModule)
  }
];
```

Comment: Made the change but its throwing this error: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: RouterModule.forRoot() called twice. Lazy loaded modules should use RouterModule.forChild() instead.
Error: RouterModule.forRoot() called twice. Lazy loaded modules should use RouterModule.forChild() instead.